# SAPUI5 Control Enable / Disable Rendering

Tags: controls, sapui5, render

I have a sap.m.TabContainer control with multiple sap.m.TabContainerItem controls. Each of the TabContainerItem controls have a number of their own controls on them. I have created a custom control (DBPanel) with a label and text field. It also has an **enabled** property for which I have overridden the **setEnabled(boolean)** method to enable/disable the internal text field within DBPanel. There are five (5) of these DBPanel controls on a specific TabContainerItem. When I call setEnabled(true) on each of these DBPanels, only three of the five become enabled. When I switch to another TabContainerItem and then back to this one, the final two DBPanels are also enabled. It is almost as if the TabContainerItem needs to be re-rendered. But I have read elsewhere that if rerender or invalidate need to be specifically called then there is something wrong with the code.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Yes, you shouldn't use rerender/invalidate directly. And the reason might be, when you switch tabs, your control gets rerendered so they become enabled. When you set disable flag, in your renderer method of your control, check that parameter and to disable or enable it. So it stays disabled even though it gets re-rendered.

Comment: Ok, makes sense, but the real problem is that the control currently visible on the screen needs to be enabled but doesn't get enabled until I select a different TabContainerItem then select the original TabContainerItem at which time things get re-rendered. Initially the control should be automatically re-rendered when I enable it but it does not.

Answer (score 0):

At your overridden method, you can try to call the original method that is extended. If you don't need extra logic rather than disabling or enabling it, you don't need to extend that method but I guess you have some.

> First check whether superclass implements the method and then call the
>   method with the original arguments

```
if (DBPanel.prototype.setEnabled)
    DBPanel.prototype.setEnabled.apply(this, arguments);
```